# Android Permission for installing other apps

Tags: android

What permission do I need to declare in my manifest in order to use my app to install other apps.

I created a Directory Explorer, but found today that if I try and use it to open APK files, the install button is disabled.

But I am able to install using regular dir explorer.

Comment: @Stanislav Bondar thanks. It looks like what I was asking. Will Test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to take runtime permission to install and access storage